# Getting all records json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get all data from table 1 in json format.

```
$arr = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY price DESC";
$statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $val){
    $arr['id'] = $val['item'];
    $arr['price'] = $val['price'];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Result:

```
{"id":"item00125","price":"112.35"}
```

The problem is that I get only one record. Why isn't the `foreach(){` not sending all the records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach ($result as $val){
 $arr[] = array(
  "id" => $val['item'],
  "price" => val['price']
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your array is being over-written every time.

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $val){
   $arr[$i]['id'] = $val['item'];
   $arr[$i]['price'] = $val['price'];
   $i++;
}   
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You got only one result because you override array key at every itration of loop

Just pass result set into `json_encode` Without using loop as

```
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

here your result variable get the all records but the problem is in the for each loop you are put the each value in position of ['id'] and ['price'] so every time for each loop put the value at that same position so means replace the value so you are getting the last value so I thing you have to put the every record in different different position like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $val)
{
    $arr[$i]['id'] = $val['item'];
    $arr[$i]['price'] = $val['price'];
    $i++; 
}   
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I hope it works fine